# No need for selecting by partial attribute?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

If

```
.animal {background: yellow}
```

will apply the styling rule to any elements with a class containing the word animal, even if it also contains other words eg...

```
<li class="toy animal">Toy Bear</li>
```

then what is the need for the below syntax for selecting by partial attribute?

```
*[class~="animal"] {background: yellow}
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no need for that. They do the same thing. Of course, the same may not be true for attributes other than class.

Comment: If this was a clarification of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725178/regarding-selecting-partial-attributes-css3-html5), note that you can edit your previous question instead of posting a new one.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is, you can use `.value` syntax only for classes, when `[attribute~="value"]` can be used to match any attribute values.

But when you use `[class~="className"]` to match `class` attribute values, it is equivalent to standard `.className` syntax.

Comment: Guys, thank you so much. I am self learning, and want to understand things fully, not just get them to work, and your responses have given me that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the [selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html), the period `.` is an alternative for the `~=` notation for the `class` attribute.

> Thus, for HTML, `div.value` and `div[class~=value]` have the same meaning

Just to clarify the `~=` meaning:

> E[foo~="bar"] an E element whose "foo" attribute value is a list of whitespace-separated values, one of which is exactly equal to "bar"

Note that this is different than `*=`

In other words, `.animal` and `[class~=animal]` (without the `*`) are the same.

Comment: Guys, thank you so much. I am self learning, and want to understand things fully, not just get them to work, and your responses have given me that. Thanks